# What's the complexity of getting an instance by key on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

GAE has a built-in data type called [ReferenceProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty), which is actually a `db.Key` as it says. It can be used to get the corresponding instance and I wonder what the complexity is?

The so called "Reference" is not like a reference in C++, which is the address, and the complexity of accessing it is O(1). And if it's just a key in the `key-value` system, I wonder it may take, like O(log) or what.

Comment: The datastore is built on a single BigTable table (well, a few of them if you count the indexes and metadata.) BigTable would be completely worthless if you couldn't fetch a value given the key in constant time; these tables are **huge**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a key in the datastore is done in constant time, it takes the same time to retrieve an entity by key no matter how many entities of that kind you have.